# Attaching @Path when there are multiple REST servers

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jetty

I have an application with 3 embedded Jetty servers with Jersey.
When I declare a @Path endpoint class, how do I determine which server/context I want it to be attached to?

Comment: What configuration code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating annotations for each server (ApiEndpoint, DashboardEndpoint, etc) and then use the Reflections library to find all of the endpoints for a given server and register them with the appropriate context/resource